# Error: TypeError: document.getElementById("count2") is null BECAUSE of conditional table. How to fix?

Tags: php, javascript, html, web-applications

I am getting an error in my page, I believe because of a conditional table not being displayed due to php if statement.

Error: TypeError: document.getElementById("count2") is null
Source File: https://www.mysite.com/js/clocktimer.js
Line: 43

I have a conditional statement:

```
<?php  if ( $this->session->userdata('days_to_challenge') > 0 ) : ?>
    <table id="mytable" border="0">
         <tr>
             <td align="center" colspan="4"><div class="numbers" id="count2" style="padding: 10px; "></div></td>
         </tr>
<?php endif; ?>
```

And my js code causing the error:

```
document.getElementById('count2').style.display="block";
document.getElementById('count2').style.width="390px";
...
```

Days to challenge has gone to zero, ie. the challenge has started so I am not displaying the countdown timer table.

What is the best way to prevent this sort of error?

Comment: I should mention that this is a small sample of code.  There are really 11 elements that will possibly be adjusted, these elements make up the countdown timer.

Answer (score 3):

Test to see if the element exists before trying to fiddle with it.

```
var count2 = document.getElementById('count2');
if (count2) {
    count2.style.display="block";
    count2.style.width="390px";
}
```

Comment: What if i am fiddling with, 11 elements, all the elements that make up the entire countdown timer table?

Comment: Then you need to balance being robust and verbose against what assumptions you can make (given you are generating the markup).

Comment: Ya that's my problem.  Don't really want 11 if statements, but not sure how else I could implement it.... hhmmmm

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
if(document.getElementById('count2')){
   document.getElementById('count2').style.display="block";
   document.getElementById('count2').style.width="390px";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure that the element exists before you write the code

```
if(document.getElementById('count2') != null) {
  document.getElementById('count2').style.display="block";
  document.getElementById('count2').style.width="390px";
}
```